# Rails 6 Active Storage image_processing gem issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image-processing, rails-activestorage

Using Rails 6.0 and 'image_processing', '~> 1.9.3'

When trying to show a cropped variant of an image with:

```
url_for(user.avatar.variant(crop: crop_geometry)&.processed)
```

I get an error:

> You must have ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick installed

I thought that image_processing gem included any dependencies relatives to this. Should I install some missing dependencies or what? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in the docs, first step, you need to instal dependencies:
https://github.com/janko/image_processing

```
1. Install ImageMagick and/or libvips:
> $ brew install imagemagick vips
```

I highly recommend using vips, it's much faster.

Comment: Indeed, I forgot to install the lib... just installed the gem. Thank you!

Comment: NOTE that changing from :mini_magick to :vips will change the variant URLs. If you're using these URLs in WYSIWYG content, the old variant URL will have a 500 response.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install library first.

For Mac user:

```
brew install imagemagick vips
```

For debian/ubuntu user:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install imagemagick libvips
```

Comment: `brew install vips` worked for me. I use MacOS 10.15.7, Rails 7.0.1